# Monitor health of HDD/SSD without S.M.A.R.T

Tags: hard-disk, usb-drive, external-hdd, badblocks, smart

Some hard disk drives (HDDs) and solid state drives (SSDs) do not provide [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data. This seems to be especially true of cheap USB HDDs.

My question is: **on a typical GNU/Linux system, can the health of such drives be monitored without deleting data from them, and if so, how?**

I know of `badblocks -n`, but have not used it. Rumour suggests that it cannot entirely be trusted to be non-destructive, though I hope the rumours are wrong. Anyhow, I would be grateful to learn of other options besides this, and preferably options that are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_software&oldid=695656324#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms).

Would it make sense to use [`fsck`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) for this purpose?

Comment: Other than S.M.A.R.T., it does look as though `badblocks` and `fsck` are [the way to go](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Comment: Not directly related, but for USB flash drives, and SD cards mounted in USB SD card readers, there is a free software (FOSS; GPLv3-licensed) program called [F3](http://superuser.com/a/589048/11574) that seems to be more appropriate than `badblocks` and perhaps `fsck`.